# iOS Smart Banner only in iOS7

Tags: javascript, ios, banner

I am having some difficulties with the Smart Banner meta tag provided by Apple. I want the Smart banner to only show-up when the user is running iOS 7 or above.
The script for checking which iOS version is used was easy:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function iOSversion() {
  if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {
      // supports iOS 2.0 and later: <http://bit.ly/TJjs1V>
      var v = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/);
      return [parseInt(v[1], 10), parseInt(v[2], 10), parseInt(v[3] || 0, 10)];
    }
  }

  ver = iOSversion();

  if (ver[0] < 7) {
    alert('iOS 6 or lower');
  }
  else {
    alert('iOS 7');
  }
  </script>
```

This works flawlessly but when I try to echo the meta tag when iOS 7 is used nothing shows up, which is nothing surprising since the meta tags are rendered before the Javascript part so the browser doesn't 'see' the meta tag. The problem is clear but the solution stays vague for me. Redirecting iOS7 users to a different page is not the right fix in my opinion but I can't find any other solution.

Do any of you have a brilliant idea for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Detect the version server side and deliver the tag that way?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't always echo the meta tag from server side. You don't have to do any user agent detection and the solution is simple

Answer (score 0):

Try [smartbanner.js](https://github.com/ain/smartbanner.js) with a meta tag to display your custom Smart App Banner on any iOS and Android platform exc. iOS below 7:

```
<meta name="smartbanner:exclude-user-agent-regex" content=".*(iPhone|iPad|iPod).*OS ([1-6])_.*">
```